# Best way to adjust loss function to train imbalanced multi label dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Been trying to train a multilabel classification CNN in Keras with a set of images where each image has a 1 for 2-4 classes and a 0 for the rest. There are a total of 608 classes, but it's a large dataset so I've narrowed it down to ~60 classes for the time being in order to make sure I can get the model to work before I train it on the larger dataset.
The problem is that when using the Binary Cross Entropy loss function, the model can just guess 0 for everything and still end up getting really good numbers. To get around this, I tried implementing a weighted BCE loss function and training the model on it:

```py
def weightedbce(y_true, y_pred):
  bce = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_true, y_pred, 
      pos_weight=40)
  return bce
```

This ended up making the model do a complete 180 and instead start guessing only 1's. I've tried to lower pos_weight to 30 and then to 20 when 30 didn't work, but to no avail.

```
19/19 [==============================] - 5s 272ms/step
testclass: [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, ... 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
predclass: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ... 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

For reference, I've been tracking the model's precision and recall as well (it would probably also help to track F1 Score but Tensorflow doesn't have it in its metrics and I couldn't figure out how to implement it). Attached image is from pos_weight=20:
[20 weight data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyxVc.png)

What would be a good number to set pos_weight to in order to balance the loss function so that it's not guessing only 1's or only 0's? Additionally, since I will later increase the amount of classes from 60 to 608, what's a good general rule for how to adjust the loss function based on how many of the classes are usually 1's and how many are usually 0's?